# style.css doesn't refresh while Bootstrap sub-theming

Tags: 8, theming

I followed the Drupal Bootstrap sub-theming documentation: basically copied the CDN starterkit and renamed all the files and it seems to work.
I then added a line to the empty css/style.css.

At first it didn't work except when I went to /admin/appearance/settings/ and clicked the advanced tab and set the theme to 'Bootstrap (Default)'.

I then made more modifications to the style.css, this time it didn't refresh on the pages. Checking the rendered pages I found the css file is coming as a mangled named css file.

What is involved in generated this mangled file and how to refresh after modifying css/style.css?

Can I choose a different theme from the Bootstrap settings page and still use my css modified styles?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mangled file comes from aggregating CSS files. You will need to clear/flush the cache in order to see changes.

You can turn CSS caching off by going to `/admin/config/development/performance` and unchecking aggregate CSS files. Now you don't need to clear the cache to see CSS changes.

[image]

**PS:** Remember to turn this back on when your website is ready for production/going live.

Comment: Now when I change libraries.yml it doesn't refresh, what is the correct way to make it refresh instantly or otherwise what is the manual way?

Comment: @Bishoy, for changes on other non **.css** or **.js** files, you will have to disable caching all together. You can by following this [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rRsOxSuJ4OU)

Comment: @Bishoy The manual way is to clear/flush the cache, but that can get annoying during development. If you want to see changes after page refresh without needing to clear the cache on non **.css** or **.js** files, follow this [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rRsOxSuJ4OU). Remember that this is just for developing, you will want to revert this once your site is ready for show time.